# How to diagnose syntax error from a parameterized SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, adodb

I'm using VBA adodb to write `INSERT` statements in a SQL Server based on Excel row contents.

I'm using parameterized queries, so my VBA code has the following form:

```vb
sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (" & Join(insertElement(0), ", ") & ") VALUES (" & Join(insertElement(2), ", ") & ")"
Set cm = New ADODB.Command

With cm
      Debug.Print (sqlStatement)
            .ActiveConnection = conn
            .CommandText = sqlStatement
            .CommandType = adCmdText
             For Each e In insertElement(1)
                Set Pm = .CreateParameter(, adVarChar, 3, 1024, e)
                .Parameters.Append Pm
             Next e
             Set rs = .Execute
        End With
```

where `insertElement(0)` is an array of field names, ...(1) is an array of values, and ...(2) is an array of placeholder `?`'s to support parameterization

When I run this code, I get an error

> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server] Incorrect syntax near 'Output'

However, when I interrogate the `sqlStatement` text, there is no 'Output' anywhere in the statement. The text is of the form:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable ([my_field_1],[my_field_2],[somefieldshaveweirdcharslike+#], ...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ...)
```

So, if I'm not providing the 'Output' command directly, and I can't directly see the statement because it's being processed on the server side, how can I diagnose the syntax?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but if I were in your shoes, I would be asking these questions: Are string values losing quotation marks? Does the ODBC driver have a trace feature I can turn on? Can I catch the query from the SQL Server side and see what it is doing from there? Does it work if I manually build the query without parameterization? (If so, what does that tell me?) If you've considered those things already, I apologize.

Comment: Yes, try to catch the query and its parameters with Sql Server Profiler.

Comment: The value `3` in `.CreateParameter(, adVarChar, 3, 1024, e)` indicated it is a value for `adParamInputOutput` as compared to `adParamInput` which has the value of 1 based on the documentation of `CreateParameter`. Because you are writing an `INSERT`, it should be 1 (`adParamInput`).

Comment: It's curious to see the whole string. Did you try to run it in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: @deseosuho Were you able to get past the errors? What worked for you?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I don't have TRACE privileges in the SQL server, so I'm continuing to work on deconstructing and trying to get simple parameterized queries to run from excel...

Comment: @deseosuho,How do you get your insertElement (0) value?

Comment: I think @shahkalpesh might be on to something. I suggest you change it from 3 to 1 and see if it fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have trace permissions in the SQL server so I had limited options for exploring server-side logging.

I ended up resolving this the brute force way, adding one field at a time until I received the error.

For my case, the underlying issue was related to using the adodb `adNumeric` parameter type for decimal values.  I switched the parameter type to `adDecimal` and then set the `NumericScale` and `Precision` values on the individual parameter objects.  The vba code structure looks something like the below

```
            For Each p In paramArr
                If p(1) = adVarChar Then
                    Set Pm = .CreateParameter(, p(1), 1, Len(p(2)), p(2))
                Else
                    Set Pm = .CreateParameter(, p(1), 1, , p(2))
                End If
                If p(1) = adDecimal Then
                    Pm.NumericScale = 3
                    Pm.Precision = 13
                End If
                .Parameters.Append Pm
            Next p
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to simply build your SQL statement by iterating your array and concatenating your values any way you see fit, rather than attempting to plug a bunch of parameters into a bunch of question marks. Something like this (I'm assuming that `insertElement` is really a two-dimensional array and not a collection; if it's really a collection then you'll need to do something similar with `For Each`):

```vb
sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (" & Join(insertElement(0), ", ") & ") VALUES ("
Set cm = New ADODB.Command

With cm
    .ActiveConnection = conn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    Dim aCount As Integer
    aCount = Ubound(insertElement(1))
    For i = 0 To aCount - 1
        sqlStatement = sqlStatement & "'" & insertElement(1,i) & "'" & _
        Iif(i <> aCount - 1, ",", "")
    Next
    .CommandText = sqlStatement
    Set rs = .Execute
End With
```

All that said, if you want to get a more in-depth understanding of where your error is happening, you might try iterating the `Connection` object's [Errors collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/errors-collection-ado?view=sql-server-2017). Since an attempt to use a connection can generate multiple errors, it can be a little hard to troubleshoot just using the `Err` object.

Finally, it would be best to set up your `INSERT` statement in a stored procedure on the server side, and pass in the values as parameters that way, unless you have no reason to be concerned about injection attacks.

Comment: In this case, I'm using Join() so there's not a trailing comma.  Unfortunately, because the server is compiling the query from a list of parameters passed separately, it doesn't appear that the `Connection` object has any access to the final query that is run.

Comment: @deseosuho Should have looked up `Join` before I answered, sorry. I've amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, but I had the same issue this week in new code and in some code which coudn't go live for months while scraching my head but I coudn't find it. And then laying it beside due to having no idea. And the internet wasn't that helpful. Well, not that big problem, because versions of the same functionality existed before, once with using the ADODB.Recordset and later building an INSERT string and shooting it with `Connection.Execute` (slightly faster than using a Recordset). But I knew, using the ADODB.Command is the fastest way, especially if You use it very often while running the program, because then You can use the precompile option with `Command.Prepared = True` and this is really the afterburner. So it was just a perfomance improvement which couldn't go live. But the new code brought me back to this issue.

**Long story short: The bug and the then obvious solution for me was: We use a field name which is a SQL reserved word, so put it in square brackets.**

Here is the code with the error:

```
Function INSERT_Category(ID, Type, Text)
    Static CMD As ADODB.Command

    If CMD Is Nothing Then
        Set CMD = New ADODB.Command
        With CMD
            .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection
            .CommandType = adCmdText
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO CATEGORIES ID, ID_TYPE, TEXT) VALUES (?,?,?)"
            .Prepared = True
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("ID", adInteger)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("ID_TYPE", adVarWChar, , 50)
            .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("TEXT", adVarWChar, , 255)
        End With
    End If

    CMD("ID") = CLng(ID)
    CMD("ID_TYPE") = CStr(Type)
    CMD("TEXT") = CStr(Text)

    CMD.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
End Function
```

As I realized where the bug is (TEXT is a reserved word) I changed just one line by putting squared brackets around the field name:

```
.CommandText = "INSERT INTO CATEGORIES ID, ID_TYPE, [TEXT]) VALUES (?,?,?)"
```

And it worked! You don't have to do it also in defining the parameter and finally while setting the value. Maybe that would even hurt, I just didn't try it.

This also applies when the field name has spaces or other special characters in it (exept underscore which is never a problem). Especially if You use mathematical operators (-, +, /, *) in the fieldname.

Well, You could avoid this by just wrapping every field name with brackets. But in my opinion this is overkill and decreases the readability. Also this manner can have drawbacks when you e.g. build a function which awaits a field name as parameter and for convenience and the aim not to forget the brackets if needed you put them in the function around the field name. And then some day later you have the idea you could use that function to put in expressions like `COUNT(Fieldname)`. And then it crashes because the whole expression is interpreted as field name.

The best option is always to avoid these kind of field names in the first place. But sometimes You find yourself in an environment where other guys defined it long ago and You are unable or just do not want to change it due to all the implications. Or you get wierd stuff from outside like Excel sheets you have to import where people are free to name their column headers with some wild texts.